# Why image of cube doesn't change when I change (0, 0, 0) to (-1, 0, 0) and (1, 0, 0)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

In the below code "cycle;" means (0, 0, 0).  They mean the starting point and terminal point, I guess. For an experiment, I tried changing (0,0,0) to (-1, 0, 0) and (1, 0, 0), then the resulting images were the same as before. Why the image doesn't change, though I changed codes?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\draw[red,fill=blue] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=green] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cycle` does not actually mean (0, 0, 0), but rather "return to the starting point of this path". The image does not change because you use relative coordinates (`++`) to create the entire path, so the starting point has no real effect.

Comment: @PaulGessler this would be true, if he would use `+(x,y,z)`. But the command `++(x,y,z)` changes also the the specified position to the new point. See my answer below.

Comment: @JMP It is as true for `++` as for `+`... ;). That is why `you don't change the object itself` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, why you dont see a change is, that tikz always crops the picture to the bounding box of the drawn object. So if you don't change the object itself, but just the positioning in the coordinate system, you'll alway get the same output. There is no reason, why one should also always plot the zero point of the coordinate system.

But however, you can see your cube moving in the picture by adding a reference point:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}   
%
\begin{document}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
        \draw[red,fill=blue] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
        \draw[red,fill=green] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        %reference point
        \filldraw[red] (0,0,0) circle (5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
        \draw[red,fill=blue] (0,0,3) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,3) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
        \draw[red,fill=green] (0,0,3) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        %reference point
        \filldraw[red] (0,0,0) circle (5pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]