# draw a little 3d graphic with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a little 3D Graphic with TikZ.

[image]

I dont know how to draw these lines on the left site...

Now, i try something like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(4,0)--(4,-1.5)--(2.5,-2.8)--(-0.5,-2.8);
    \draw (4,0)--(2.5,-1)--(-0.5,-1);
    \draw (2.5,-1)--(2.5,-2.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: This may help you... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303707/why-image-of-cube-doesnt-change-when-i-change-0-0-0-to-1-0-0-and-1-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your diagram is not very clear, especially the arrows. So I leave the arrow to you. An arrow in the middle of a line can be drawn as in [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3161/156344).

If you want the arrows to have an "over each other" effect, you may borrow `preaction`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    my line/.style={preaction={draw=white,line width=#1},-latex},
    my line/.default=3pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) -- (6,0) -- (6,-3) -- (4,-5) -- (4,-2) -- (6,0)
      (0,-2) -- (4,-2) (0,-5) -- (4,-5);
\draw[my line] (5,-5) -- (5,1);
\draw[my line] (5,-2.5) -- (9,-2.5);
\draw[my line=5pt,very thick] (7,-.5) -- (2,-5.5) 
    node[pos=0.8,above left] {$M_b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]